# How can I transform this multidimensional array into an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am not asking you to write code for me. Any direction would be appreciated.

I have an array in the following format:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
  (
  [title] => Here is the first title
  [count] => 765
  [description] => Description
  )
[1] => Array
  (
  [title] => The second title
  [count] => 90
  [description] => Description
  [other] => Data
  )
[2] => Array
  (
  [title] => A third title
  [count] => 1080
  [description] => Description
  )
)
```

I am wondering how I can transform this into something like below, using the 'title' and 'count' data.

```
Array
(
[Here is the first title] => 765
[The second title] => 90
[A third title] => 1080
)
```

At the moment I have created the following code:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($inputarray as $value) {
    $results[] = $value["count"];
}
```

Which gives me the below:

```
Array
(
[0] => 765
[1] => 90
[2] => 1080
)
```

But I'm not sure how to make the title data the new key for its associated count data. Is there a function that will do this? Can a modification be made to the above or is it more complicated? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just populate the keys of the new array explicitly with the titles:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($inputarray as $value) {
    $results[$value["title"]] = $value["count"];
}
```

Just be aware that any entries with the same title will overwrite the previous one, as array keys must be unique. I have doubts that this is the best way to achieve your goals, but it's what you asked for.

Comment: Thnks for your help. Do you mean if one array has the same title? If so, that won't be a probablem as it's checked upon entry before it gets to this stage.

Comment: That's correct, anything you use as a key must be unique or it will overwrite the previous array item that has that key. For instance `$arr = array(1=>1, 1=>2);` will result in array with only one value (the last one, 2). Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Despite the fact the title's are unique, I am ending up with the following result:

`Array ( [] => 1080 )`

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be done is with array_reduce and a closure (Requires PHP 5.3+)

```
$res = array_reduce($array, function (&$results, $v){
     $results[$v["title"]] = $v["count"];
}, array());
```